# How to prevent JFrame from coming to top after closing JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am automating certain actions on a web browser. Upon completing a number of actions, a `JOptionPane` would pop up to ask the user if they would like to continue.

After I clicked 'Yes', my main frame would pop up over my web browser, which ruins my workflow.

I could get the browser to move to the front of the main frame, but I would like to know if it is possible to prevent the main frame from popping up after selecting an option in the `JOptionPane` dialog?

Comment: Normally you specify a JFrame as the parent window of the JOptionPane. Try using "null" for the parent, then hopefully the JOptionPane will work independently of the JFrame.

Comment: @camickr I have been using "null" all along and it doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any options on `JOptionPane` so I started looking into how easy it would be to reimplement it using another `JFrame`. I decided to disable the main frame and enable it back later (it seems that this is what `JOptionPane` does internally anyway) and before I reimplemented `JOptionPane` I have noticed that it solves the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton button = new JButton("hello");
    button.addActionListener(e -> {
        frame.setEnabled(false); // disable main frame
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "hello");
        frame.setEnabled(true); // enable main frame
    });
    frame.setContentPane(button);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 480);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

However I am not sure if this will work on all platforms. Does it help you?

If not, I would recommend replacing `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "hello");` with your own `JFrame` so you have full control over it. You will have to add `WindowListener` to enable main frame when it's closed. However you will loose a blocking functionality - this may be more difficult to implement than it's worth it.